# how to restore db2 10.1 database backup on db2 9.7

Tags: database, db2, database-backups, db2-luw

I am trying to restore the database backup taken from db2 10.1 system, now i want to restore it to db2 9.7 system on windows machine.

below is the error i am getting-

> SQL2542N  No match for a database image file was found based on  the
>   source database alias "DBASPECT" and timestamp  "20160317210717"
>   provided.

Answer (score 2):

You can restore a DB2 database backup to the same or newer DB2 version. The reason is that the DB2 software needs to know how to handle the image/content. With features added in new DB2 versions, the DB2 9.7 system on your Windows machine cannot know how to handle those V10.1 structures and metadata.

You could try to restore to a DB2 10.1, then extract the schema and data with tools like `db2look` or `db2move` and `export`. You would have scripts and CSV files to rebuild the database on a V9.7 level.